# pressing alt+s key combination using applescipt

Tags: applescript

how do I tell applescipt to hit alt? 
I want to press simultaneously alt+s

This code does not work:

`tell application "System Events" to keystroke "s" using alt`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "s" using option down
```

or

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "s" using {option down}
```

You can use the list option if you want to simulate multiple keys like command down/‌control down/‌option down/‌shift down.

Easily found in the scripting dictionary of **System Events**

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg